# Weird behaviour constraint using simple symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I'm trying to use a simple form definition to filter some data, so I create the form with no class attached(expecting to use getData() function) and then work with the array of parameters passed to the form, but the form comes always invalid. Result that the form is trying to validate a parameter that do not belong to the context of form.

I'm getting this validation error on the field "almacen": 
This value should not be blank.

With cause:

> Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data[almacen].responsable = null

I tried using `cascade_validation=false` but did't work.

In the controller action I declared:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $informeStock = $this->createForm(new BusquedaInformeStockType());

    $informeStock->handleRequest($request);
    if ($informeStock->isSubmitted() && $informeStock->isValid()) {
        $data = $informStock->getData();
        // the action logic...
    }

    ...
}
```

I have a simple form definition, with an entity form type declared and no data_class asociated to the form.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('almacen', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'BusetaBodegaBundle:Bodega',
            'placeholder' => '---Seleccione---',
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Bodega',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ))
        ...
        ...
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
}
```

And this is the definition of the entity Bodega:

```
class Bodega
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codigo", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $codigo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Buseta\BodegaBundle\Entity\Tercero", inversedBy="bodega")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $responsable;

    ...
}
```

In previous versions of the entity Bodega the parameter "responsable" was left in blank, so there is some rows in the db thas has no "responsable" asociated.
But despite that this should not be happening right? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have an [entity form field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) with validation constraints:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Buseta\BodegaBundle\Entity\Tercero", inversedBy="bodega")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $responsable;
```

This is your problem - Assert [not blank](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html)

> Validates that a value is not blank, defined as not strictly false,
>   not equal to a blank string and also not equal to null

You have few choices, either add validation group([read this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html) and [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)) or simple remove that Assert. Also its better to use [@Assert\Valid](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) for associations like that.

Comment: That field `$resposable` is part of the Bodega entity, but I'm not defining this entity, I only use Bodega to fill the "select" on the filter form.